# Programmatically get source of a Template Field

Tags: templates, datasource

I have field in Template like Multilist with Search and Treelist with search. In these fields in the source a start search location is specified as below:

[image]

I need to find out all templates programmatically that contains fields whose **Source** starts with StartSearchLocation = {11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}. Please suggest how can i achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to get or modify the items.

Reference : https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

You need to write a Script that recurse through the templates tree and get all items. Then you can check value of the the Source field that contains or starts with StartSearchLocation = {11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}..

You could also do this in code.(using same logic as defined above)

Exaample Script :

```
$results = gci -path "/sitecore/templates" -recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Template field" -and $_.Fields["Source"].Value.StartsWith("StartSearchLocation={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}") }
$results
```